# Python `os.path.isfile()` always returns TRUE

Tags: python

```
import os.path
import sys

try:
    os.path.isfile("random3664746474746.txtxtxtxtx")
    #os.path.isfile(ros.path.join(os.getcwd(), a))
except:
    print("ERROR!")
    exit(3)
```

I'am confused. No matter what file name I give it, it always returns TRUE! 
Am I missing something?

Comment: `os.path.isfile("file")` will give you `True/False` and hence it will never throw an exception. Instead, you may want to use `if/else`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it returns FALSE it's not an exception

```
import os.path

if not os.path.isfile("random3664746474746.txtxtxtxtx"):
    print("ERROR!")
    exit(3)
```